# Any concern over supporting multiple "." in filename for modern filesystems?

Tags: filesystems

We are implementing an API that makes use of internal databases.  We don't really have any control over which filesystems this will be implemented on.

My question is, does any modern filesystem not support multiple "." characters in a filename?  (IE we want to use foo.bar.db.....)  We have already blown through that massive 8 characters allowed by dos so I am not too worried about the 8.3 rule.

Regards,
PablitoRun

Comment: One can't prove that there ISN'T some rare and esoteric thing out there somewhere that somebody uses and which enforces draconian limitations, but I wouldn't worry about it!

Comment: I'd not be concerned of multiple dots. Much more of casing and allowed characters in file names. Make 100% sure you consistently case file names and do not rely on any specific casing strategy.